# Android: Logging on to SSH server for internet access

Tags: android, ssh

At my campus, to get internet connection, I need to log on to a SSH server like they write:

> ...you must manually log in to the firewall server, by establishing a **pseudo-tty-less ssh connection** to it. The following command can be used on most systems: ssh -T -l [username] [server-URL]
>   I must be logged on to the server for as long as I want internet.

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this on Android?

I have a little experience in writing basic apps for Android, but not much with SSH, any help is appreciated.

**/Update**
Tried ConnectBot, but the server replies "You may only connect without a pseudo-tty!" at login attempt. I have no idea what "pseudo-tty" is, and I have looked in the settings of ConnectBot, there is no mention of this.

**/Update2** 
Searched for any further info about the pseudo-tty-less function, in connection with OpenSSH. No luck so far, only a definition of the -T parameter which has no equivalent in ConnectBot.

**/bump**
Still very interested in any further suggestions!

Comment: Pseudo-TTY is used for opening a Shell in the other end, usually when you SSH to some SSH server you will be presented with a Shell on the server you log on. K-net, which you are using here do not want to allocate memory for each user on their firewalls for the shells, hence you disable the Pseudo-TTY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at Connectbot, it has an ability to tunnel ports. I'm not sure if it solves your problem though.

Comment: Thanks, I tried ConnectBot. I can connect to the server, but after I write my password it says "You may only connect without a pseudo-tty!"

Answer (score 1):

After struggling, I finally got it to work:

1. Download BotSync from the market,
2. Set up the connection entering the server you want to connect to, port 22, your username/password, leave the `remote dir` and `local dir` fields blank, a large number (e.g 9000) into the "period" field and start the connection.

You'll get an error message `Error:Illegal sftp packet len:xxxxxxxx`. Just ignore it, you're already logged in.

Answer (score 0):

ConnectBot is open source, so is OpenSSH. Take a look at what -T does in OpenSSH, and see if there's similar functionality in ConnectBot.

Comment: The only info I could find in OpenSSH about the -T parameter was "-T Disable pseudo-tty allocation.". I can find no such functionality in ConnectBot. It doesn't really get me closer, but thanks for the tip.